# SQL Date change upon CSV import

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, ssis-2012

Weird situation during `.csv` file import via SSIS into a SQL Server table.

CSV date `25-May-46` is imported into a `NVARCHAR` column.

When selecting that column on

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CAST(date_of_birth AS DATE), 111), '/', '-')
```

I get '2046-05-25'

When converting that column to a date in Excel, I get '1946-05-25'

Does anyone have an idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the "Two Digit Year Cutoff" parameter at the SSMS - rightclick on your SQL Server - Server Properties - Advanced Settings.
Default value is 2049, and you have expected result for this setting.
Set it to 2045, to get '1946-05-25' on SQL Server.

Also you can check/set this value like that:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'two digit year cutoff' --to check

EXEC sys.sp_configure N'two digit year cutoff', N'2045' --to set
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pavel, you are a damn rock star!! Thanks!! :)) That was bothering me for more than a day worth of researching that problem!  THANKS!

Comment: Wow, I'm a rock star! Thanks! :) Btw, your question was clearly formulated, setting all wrong assumptions aside.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a mismatch in the date format in the csv vs your machines localization. I reckon you should review the date format and check that it matches with you machines settings